# How to compile kernel for KVM guest (without paravirtualization)?

Tags: configuration, linux-kernel, kvm, virtualization

So I have a KVM machine, where I run an Ubuntu 12.04 (server edition).
I want to compile a minimalistic kernel for the KVM guest, but I only found the howto for [hosts, and guests with paravirtualization](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Tuning_Kernel).

I want to compile a kernel for a guest. Nothing more. With only the things it needs.

Comment: First - why do you not want to use the PV drivers? That should make things easier. Second: Why do you want to do this? Are you simulating an ebedded system?

Comment: I don't need them. Minimalistic: Throw out everything you don't need. It's not a simulation, a real KVM server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about paravirtualization, then compiling a minimalistic kernel for a KVM guest is the same as compiling a minimalistic kernel for hardware.  There is lots of documentation available on the latter topic:

https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+build+minimal+kernel